# How to single function to call multiple activities?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm practicing android. In my practice app there is a Activity called Land calculation activity, there are nine buttons in this activity to call nine new activities. How can i use a single function to call all different activities. Here is code that i'm using and it is working correctly but what i want is a single function .

```
public class land_calculation extends AppCompatActivity {

private LinearLayout landone, landtwo, landthree, landfour, landfive, landsix, landseven, landeight, landnine;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_land_calculation);

 landone = findViewById(R.id.landone);
 landtwo = findViewById(R.id.landtwo);
 landthree = findViewById(R.id.landthree);
 landfour = findViewById(R.id.landfour);
 landfive = findViewById(R.id.landfive);
 landsix = findViewById(R.id.landsix);
 landseven = findViewById(R.id.landseven);
 landeight = findViewById(R.id.landeight);
 landnine = findViewById(R.id.landnine);


    landone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(land_calculation.this, landOne.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    landtwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(land_calculation.this, landTwo.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    landthree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(land_calculation.this, landThree.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    landfour.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(land_calculation.this, landFour.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    landfive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(land_calculation.this, landFive.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    landsix.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(land_calculation.this, landSix.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    landseven.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(land_calculation.this, landSeven.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    landeight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(land_calculation.this, landEight.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    landnine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(land_calculation.this, landNine.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });




}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, Have a look.

Implement `View.onClickListner` in your activity.

```
public class land_calculation extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
```

now this override the `onClick` method

now, bind your button to `onClickListner` in your `oncreate` method, by doing this.

```
landone.setOnClickListener(this)
landtwo.setOnClickListener(this)
//bind all the nine button
```

Now,Edit your `onClick` method as below

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = null;
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.landone:
                i = new Intent(land_calculation.this, landOne.class);
                break;
            case R.id.landtwo:
                i = new Intent(land_calculation.this, landTwo.class);
                break;

            //put all your case here
        }
        startActivity(i);

    }
```

**EDIT**

```
public class land_calculation extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private LinearLayout landone, landtwo, landthree, landfour, landfive, landsix, landseven, landeight, landnine;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_land_calculation);

        landone = findViewById(R.id.landone);
        landtwo = findViewById(R.id.landtwo);
        landthree = findViewById(R.id.landthree);
        landfour = findViewById(R.id.landfour);
        landfive = findViewById(R.id.landfive);
        landsix = findViewById(R.id.landsix);
        landseven = findViewById(R.id.landseven);
        landeight = findViewById(R.id.landeight);
        landnine = findViewById(R.id.landnine);
        

        landone.setOnClickListener(this);
        landtwo.setOnClickListener(this);
        landthree.setOnClickListener(this);
        landfour.setOnClickListener(this);
        landfive.setOnClickListener(this);
        landsix.setOnClickListener(this);
        landseven.setOnClickListener(this);
        landeight.setOnClickListener(this);
        landnine.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = null;
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.landone:
                i = new Intent(land_calculation.this, landOne.class);
                break;
            case R.id.landtwo:
                i = new Intent(land_calculation.this, landTwo.class);
                break;

            //put all your case here
        }
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, as i'm very new to android can you please elaborate further the `oncreate()` . I don't know how to use `oncreate()`

Comment: It's there in your activity class. ```protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)```
Let me know if furthure understanding needed. Happy to help :)

Comment: Hi, i am getting this error  - error: class, interface, or enum expected
    public void onClick(View v) {

Comment: Please move the method outside of the onCreate(). Only button binding will be there any other method will be outside the onCreate().

Comment: I did same . There is no error but now when i open app on phone and click on the activity app crashes ...

Comment: I edited my answer as per your class. Look at the edit you'll understand

Answer (score -1):

public class LandCalculation extends AppCompatActivity implements
View.OnClickListener
{

```
private LinearLayout landone, landtwo, landthree, landfour, landfive,
landsix, landseven, landeight, landnine;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_land_calculation);

    landone = findViewById(R.id.landone);
    landtwo = findViewById(R.id.landtwo);
    landthree = findViewById(R.id.landthree);
    landfour = findViewById(R.id.landfour);
    landfive = findViewById(R.id.landfive);
    landsix = findViewById(R.id.landsix);
    landseven = findViewById(R.id.landseven);
    landeight = findViewById(R.id.landeight);
    landnine = findViewById(R.id.landnine);
    initilizeListener();
}

void initilizeListener() {
    landone.setOnClickListener(this)
    landtwo.setOnClickListener(this)
    landthree.setOnClickListener(this)
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = null;
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.landone:
            i = new Intent(land_calculation.this, landOne.class);
            break;
        case R.id.landtwo:
            i = new Intent(land_calculation.this, landTwo.class);
            break;
    }
    startActivity(i);
}
```

}